# How do I create a Kaplan Meier plot in R with long data?

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I want to gather some basic statistics about `sales` data using the Kaplan Meier model. My data is in long format, with each observed unit having a separate row for each day it was on the market, like so:

```
id     date        time_on_market     sold
1      2022-01-01  0                  0
1      2022-01-02  1                  0
1      2022-01-03  2                  1
2      2022-02-14  0                  0
2      2022-02-15  1                  1
```

Is there a way to do this without pivoting the data into wide format?

I have made survival curves with a KM before when the data was in wide format, for example:

```
id     date        time_on_market     sold
1      2022-01-03  2                  1
2      2022-02-15  1                  1
3      2022-03-30  30                 0
```

where each row being a unique observation, the total time on market, and the dummy variable for if it sold, but I can't seem to figure out the [documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/survival/html/Surv.html) to create the right kind of objects when the data is long. If I just try to create a curve using

```
pacman::p_load(survival, ggsurvfit, gtsummary, tidycmprsk, survminer)

survfit2(Surv(time_on_market, sold) ~ 1, data = sales) %>% 
  ggsurvfit()
```

the resulting curve is incorrect.
Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 2):

The rows you need are already present in the data. Just extract them using `slice_max`

```r
library(tidyverse)

sales_filtered <- sales %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  slice_max(time_on_market)

sales_filtered
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#> # Groups:   id [2]
#>      id date       time_on_market  sold
#>   <int> <chr>               <int> <int>
#> 1     1 2022-01-03              2     1
#> 2     2 2022-02-15              1     1
```

Now you can do:

```r
survfit2(Surv(time_on_market, sold) ~ 1, data = sales_filtered) %>% 
  ggsurvfit()
```

Comment: But surely there exists a way within the `Surv` function to handle data in the format that I have it in, correct? Is there a way to use the existing functions in the package without making a copy of my data?

Comment: @nooshrpak I'm not sure why you would think that. Your data is in an unusual format for survival analysis, where typically there is one row per individual. What you have is a data frame with lots of extra rows that are not used by the modelling function, so what you are saying is "why can't the software filter my data for me?", even though as I've shown, it's trivial to filter out the unused rows. If you're worried about making a copy, you could do it all in a dplyr pipeline. I only created a copy in my example to demonstrate the correct format.